# rule engine Drools and JESS (work flow engine )

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, business-rules, rule-engine

I came to know about 2 rule engine JESS(Work flow engine) and drools by reading lots of document so can you please suggest me which one will be good ?

My requirement is something like i am checking source code and if any standard method or approach is missing get a log or report or any kind of flag so which one will be good for me ?

i read about both of 2 from here

[Pros and cons of Java rules engines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167358/pros-and-cons-of-java-rules-engines)

http://www.jessrules.com/guidelines.shtml

http://blog.athico.com/2007/08/jboss-drools-vs-ilog-jrules.html

[Drools vs JBPM ? differences, pros and cons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736143/drools-vs-jbpm-differences-pros-and-cons)

but still confuse so can any one suggest me a right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
which one will be good ?
```

Any of them are good. I also used Drools, its good enough.

```
My requirement is something like i am checking source code and if any standard method or approach is missing get a log or report or any kind of flag so which one will be good for me ?
```

I think what you need here is [maven-checkstyle-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/)

Comment: maven-checkstyle-plugin i found that it is checking only abc.java file but i donot want any restriction like this means i want to check javascript file or xml file or configration file i am ready to write rule so is ti possible in maven-checkstyle-plugin ?

Comment: And rules are user defined